# Unable to run a Blazor Server App on Microsoft Visual Studio IDE Version 17.2.0 Preview 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a Blazor Server project created with **Microsoft Visual Studio IDE Version 17.2.0 Preview 1** and it was debugging and starting without any problems.

When I upgraded to **Version 17.2.0 Preview 5.0**, I am unable to build the project, run the project or even close the IDE. Popup UIs are showing up each time I try to do any of these actions.

I am now closing the IDE using the Task Manager. I have attached screenshots with descriptions and if anyone has ever solved this please assist me to get over this.

**I have tried the following:**

1. Created a new project but the problem remains.
2. Repaired Visual Studio IDE but the problem remains.

**I am using:**

1. Blazor Server and .NET 6.
2. The IDE is Microsoft Visual Studio IDE Community Edition Version 17.2.0 Preview 5.0

I will appreciate any help I can get.

[image: This error shows up when I try to debug the project]

**The above error shows up when I try to debug the project:**

[image: This error shows up when I try to close the IDE:]

**The above error shows up when I try to close the IDE:**

[image: Version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Blazor project in Visual Studio 2022 17.2.0 Preview 5.0, built the project and ran without encountering this issue.

Please try closing Visual Studio, deleting the project's .vs and bin/obj folders, and reloading the project.

If the issue still exists, please run [/safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022) at the **development command prompt**, it will check if third-party packages and extensions are causing the issue.

Comment: Deleting the .vs, bin/obj folders worked as they were correctly recreated. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update my launchsettings profile, the "https" one works and the "IIS Express" on I deleted.

FROM:

```
"IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "hotReloadEnabled": true,
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"
},
```

TO:

```
"https": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "hotReloadEnabled": true,
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:62099/;http://localhost:5058"
},
```